# Infix to postfix conversion in C programming (A^B^C)/ (D*E)

Tags: c, postfix-mta, infix-notation

I'm coding in C that converts infix expression to postfix. I have run it without errors but it is not giving me the right output. The output is suppose to be in form:

`(A^B^C)/(D*E)` = `ABC^^DE*/` but the output is `AB^C^DE*/`

The convert method is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define SIZE 50
char s[SIZE];
int top=-1;      
push(char elem)
{                       
    s[++top]=elem;
}

char pop()
{                      
    return(s[top--]);
}

int pr(char elem)
{                 
    switch(elem)
    {
    case '#': return 0;
    case '(': return 1;
    case '+':
    case '-': return 2;
    case '*':
    case '/': return 3;
    }
}

void main()
{                        
    char infx[50],pofx[50],ch,elem;
    int i=0,k=0;
    clrscr();
    printf("\n\nRead the Infix Expression ? ");
    scanf("%s",infx);
    push('#');
    while( (ch=infx[i++]) != '\0')
    {
    if( ch == '(') push(ch);
    else
    if(isalnum(ch)) pofx[k++]=ch;
      else
    if( ch == ')')
    {
        while( s[top] != '(')
      pofx[k++]=pop();
        elem=pop(); 
    }
    else
    {       
        while( pr(s[top]) >= pr(ch) )
      pofx[k++]=pop();
        push(ch);
    }
    }
    while( s[top] != '#')     
  pofx[k++]=pop();
    pofx[k]='\0';          
    printf("\n\nGiven Infix Expn: %s  Postfix Expn: %s\n",infx,pofx);
    getch();
}
```